# Flow chart in Highcharts adding list and line breaks

Tags: javascript, highcharts, flowchart

https://jsfiddle.net/ermacwins/817zry6a/7/

I am creating a flow chart

3 things have me stuck

## 1 (bottom blue boxes)

I can add 1 line break
I cannot add 2 line breaks.
The 2nd 
 just get ignored

## 2 (bottom blue boxes)

I cannot add an unordered list
The html tags gets ignored.

## 3

Can't get the arrow's appearance to change (fattened or shortened)

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    events: {
      load: function() {

        //Draw the flow chart
        var ren = this.renderer,
          colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors,
          rightArrow = ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 100, 0, 'L', 95, 5, 'M', 100, 0, 'L', 95, -5],
          leftArrow = ['M', 100, 0, 'L', 0, 0, 'L', 5, 5, 'M', 0, 0, 'L', 5, -5];

        // Headers
        ren.label('', 20, 40)
          .css({
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          })
          .add();
        ren.label('', 220, 40)
          .css({
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          })
          .add();
        ren.label('', 440, 40)
          .css({
            fontWeight: 'bold'
          })
          .add();

        // Top labels
        ren.label('Risk<br/>Rewards', 10, 82)
          .attr({
            fill: colors[2],
            stroke: 'white',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            padding: 5,
            r: 5,
            height: 90,
            width: 110
          })
          .css({
            color: 'black'
          })
          .add()
          .shadow(true);

        ren.label('The<br/>Determination', 160, 82)
          .attr({
            fill: colors[2],
            stroke: 'white',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            padding: 5,
            r: 5,
            height: 90,
            width: 110
          })
          .css({
            color: 'black'
          })
          .add()
          .shadow(true);

        ren.label('Action<br/>Packed Theme', 310, 82)
          .attr({
            fill: colors[2],
            stroke: 'white',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            padding: 5,
            r: 5,
            height: 90,
            width: 110
          })
          .css({
            color: 'black'
          })
          .add()
          .shadow(true);

        ren.label('Awaiting<br/>Your<br/>Reply', 460, 82)
          .attr({
            fill: colors[2],
            stroke: 'white',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            padding: 5,
            r: 5,
            height: 90,
            width: 110
          })
          .css({
            color: 'black'
          })
          .add()
          .shadow(true);

        ren.label('Final<br/>Destination', 610, 82)
          .attr({
            fill: colors[2],
            stroke: 'white',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            padding: 5,
            r: 5,
            height: 90,
            width: 110
          })
          .css({
            color: 'black'
          })
          .add()
          .shadow(true);

        // Arrow
        ren.path(rightArrow)
          .attr({
            'stroke-width': 2,
            stroke: colors[1]
          })
          .translate(120, 100)
          .add();


        // Bottom labels
        ren.label('84 cases<br/>Chemistry characterization', 30, 135)
          .attr({
            fill: colors[0],
            stroke: 'white',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            padding: 5,
            r: 5,
            height: 100
          })
          .css({
            color: 'white',
            width: '110px',
            fontSize: '8px'
          })
          .add()
          .shadow(true);

        ren.label('1285 colors<br/><br/>Cases in dialogue', 180, 135)
          .attr({
            fill: colors[0],
            stroke: 'white',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            padding: 5,
            r: 5,
            height: 100
          })
          .css({
            color: 'white',
            width: '110px',
            fontSize: '8px'
          })
          .add()
          .shadow(true);

        ren.label('60 drones<br/><br/>Sources are to<br/> be be named', 330, 135)
          .attr({
            fill: colors[0],
            stroke: 'white',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            padding: 5,
            r: 5,
            height: 100
          })
          .css({
            color: 'white',
            width: '110px',
            fontSize: '8px'
          })
          .add()
          .shadow(true);

        ren.label('1162 metals<br/>Awaiting signatures<br/>Cases unknown', 480, 135)
          .attr({
            fill: colors[0],
            stroke: 'white',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            padding: 5,
            r: 5,
            height: 100
          })
          .css({
            color: 'white',
            width: '110px',
            fontSize: '8px'
          })
          .add()
          .shadow(true);

        ren.label('', 630, 135)
          .attr({
            fill: colors[0],
            stroke: 'white',
            'stroke-width': 2,
            padding: 5,
            r: 5,
            height: 100,
            width: 110
          })
          .css({
            color: 'white',
            width: '110px',
            fontSize: '8px'
          })
          .add()
          .shadow(true);
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Active directory Projections',
    style: {
      color: 'black'
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: the jsFiddle link you've posted doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to edit your post and add the appropriate link to JSFiddle example.

> I can add 1 line break I cannot add 2 line breaks. The 2nd 
>   just get ignored

It's because every string provided to `renderer` methods is parsed by some rules, and among others, two and more `<br/>` elements placed one by one are not respected. In order to make it work, just need to set `baseline` parameter equal to `true` when creating the label, then it should be actually the HTML element instead of `<tspan>`.

> I cannot add an unordered list The html tags gets ignored.

Just like before, if you set `baseline`, then the `<ul>` should be visible.
Here is the code:

```
ren.label('1285 colors<br/><br/>Cases in dialogue:<br/><ul><li>Something...</li></ul>', 180, 135, "rect", 0, 0, true)
```

> Can't get the arrow's appearance to change (fattened or shortened)

It's not a big deal, because it's enough to change the path on an arrow a bit, and increase its `stroke-width` parameter to make it fattened, for example:

```
var rightArrow = ['M', 0, 0, 'L', 45, 0, 'L', 40, 10, 'M', 45, 0, 'L', 40, -10],

    ren.path(rightArrow)
      .attr({
        'stroke-width': 4,
        stroke: colors[1]
      })
      .translate(120, 100)
      .add();
```

**Live example:** http://jsfiddle.net/e8twxurz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label